# How to insert a string if a table returns null?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, testing, sql-insert

I'm attempting to adapt a query someone else wrote to do some testing. There are several queries in this file that will pull data and as long as no results are generated then everything is good. There are several spots in this query that I don't understand but the only thing I really want to know is how I can insert a 'PASS' or 'FAIL' value if no results are generated.

```
declare @i int, @d nvarchar (3), @max int, @db nvarchar (100), 
@query nvarchar (max), @base_db_name nvarchar(50), @use_loop int;

select name
from sys.databases


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TABLE1
END

create table #TABLE1 (
    Column1 datatype,
    Column2 datatype,
    Column3 datatype,

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TABLE2
END

create table #TABLE2 (
    Column1 datatype,
    Column2 datatype,
    Column3 datatype,
    )   

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE3') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TABLE3
END

create table #TABLE3 (
    Column1 datatype,
    Column2 datatype,
    Column3 datatype,
    )

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE4') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TABLE4
END

create table #TABLE4 (
    Column1 datatype,
    Column2 datatype,
    Column3 datatype,
    )


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE5') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TABLE5
END

create table #TABLE5 (
    Column1 datatype,
    Column2 datatype,
    Column3 datatype,
    )

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE6') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TABLE6
END

create table #TABLE6 (
    Column1 datatype,
    Column2 datatype,
    Column3 datatype,
    )



While @i <= @max
Begin
    if @use_loop = 1    
    Begin   
        set @d = CAST(@i as nvarchar);
        Set @db = @base_db_name +@d+ '].dbo.'; 
    End


Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
    ' as nvarchar(max))
Insert INTO #TABLE1
Execute (@query)


Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
    ' as nvarchar(max))
Insert INTO #TABLE2
Execute (@query)


Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
    ' as nvarchar(max))
Insert INTO #TABLE3
Execute (@query)

Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
    ' as nvarchar(max))
Insert INTO #TABLE3
Execute (@query)


Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
    ' as nvarchar(max))
Insert INTO #TABLE4
Execute (@query)


Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
    ' as nvarchar(max))
Insert INTO #TABLE5
Execute (@query)


Set @query = cast('
    *QUERY GOES HERE*
        ' as nvarchar(max))
    Insert INTO #TABLE6
    Execute (@query)



    set @i = @i + 1;
End
GO

Select *
from #TABLE1;

Select *
from #TABLE2;

Select *
from #TABLE3;

Select *
from #TABLE4;

Select *
from #TABLE5;

Select *
from #TABLE6;
```

Its really long I realize but I tried to keep it simple and only get the meat and potatoes. All I want to know is when the query pulls results from tables 1-6 at the end, how can I insert into an entirely different table (say ResultsTable) with a value of pass / fail if nothing shows up?

Comment: The batch tag was because this script is called from a batch script. I just added it without thinking about that I hadn't referenced that in the post.

Comment: Could someone explain why I've been downvoted?

Comment: Is `ResultsTable` already an existing table? Do you only want it populated in the event that all other tables are blank?

Comment: Yes ResultsTable is an existing table. I'd like it to populate that table with "Pass" if no results are returned for any of the 6 tables and "Fail" if any results are returned at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest way, although admittedly not elegant, would just be to count the number of records in the 6 tables you've created:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table1)
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table2)
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table3)
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table4)
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table5)
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table6)) > 0
  INSERT INTO ResultsTable (FieldName) VALUES ('Fail');
ELSE
  INSERT INTO ResultsTable (FieldName) VALUES ('Pass');
```

Comment: hey elegance is overrated sometimes. I thought this would be fairly simple but for the life of me I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks!